# Best Practices in Razor Pages: Using AJAX or Handlers for post/get requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Generally speaking when you're doing a POST request you want to reload the page. Though not always. When using a GET method to retrieve data you may consider using AJAX. However I am relatively new to Razor Pages and ASP.net core altogether. I am being told we should always load the page. That since we are using Razor Pages it is not correct to use AJAX to submit anything to the code-behind. Otherwise whats the purpose of using Razor Pages.

My concern is it leaves a bad user experience. If I want to run a report, retrieve the data, and show the data using a handler. I require the page to reload. If I use AJAX I require JSON but it doesn't require the page to reload. If I use a handler I can get back a model which I can use to display on the reloaded page without having to convert it to JSON.

What is the best practice with Razor Pages? It seems like if you must reload every time we are going back in time to 2003.

Comment: Reloading an entire page every time you want to hit an API endpoint (Controller) it's generally NOT a good idea, partial views it's the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use AJAX to submit to the Razor Pages code-behind, I've built a blog application's Admin Panel based on this with satisfactory results https://github.com/FanrayMedia/Fanray

The Razor Pages model-behind class serves as convenient end points that return JSON to your AJAX calls. For example, my blog's composer which is a Razor Page has an **auto-save draft** feature, in the [view](https://github.com/FanrayMedia/Fanray/blob/master/src/Core/Fan.WebApp/Manage/Admin/Compose.cshtml) I have [js code](https://github.com/FanrayMedia/Fanray/blob/master/src/Core/Fan.WebApp/Manage/Admin/client/js/blog-compose.js#L154) like

```
axios.post('/admin/compose?handler=save', this.payload, { headers: { 'XSRF-TOKEN': this.tok } }) ...
```

which posts to this [model-behind class code](https://github.com/FanrayMedia/Fanray/blob/master/src/Core/Fan.WebApp/Manage/Admin/Compose.cshtml.cs#L246)

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostSaveAsync([FromBody]PostVM post)
{
  ...

  return new JsonResult(postVM);
}
```

Hope this helps!